# What kind of encryption is a one-time pad?

Tags: cryptography, encryption

Is it a substitution cipher or a stream cipher or both?

Comment: This sounds like homework .. hah :P

Comment: Bruce Schneier memorizes his one time pads :)

Answer (score 19):

It is not a substitution cipher.  Schneier classifies it as a stream cipher because it converts plaintext to ciphertext one bit or byte at a time, generally by XORing the plaintext with a "keystream".

In most stream ciphers the keystream is only pseudo-random, but in a classic "one-time pad" the keystream is entirely random.  It can be though of as a fresh key for each message, equal in length to the plaintext, which is typically combined with the plaintext via XOR so it is easy to get plaintext back from the ciphertext with another XOR.  The trick is getting the pad itself - good quality truly random keying material - to the other end of the communications channel, out-of-band....

See also [One-time pad - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad)

Answer (score -1):

@nealmcb is correct that a one-time pad (OTP) is a stream cipher.  However, he's *not* correct that the defining characteristic is the quality of the randomness.  What defines an OTP is:

1. The key material is only used once
2. The key material is the same length as the plaintext

As with any other decent cipher, the quality of your key material is paramount.  However, you *can* implement an OTP with not-very-random numbers -- it just reduces the security of the key.

#### Edit

Based on the discussion below, clarification is in order.

A crypto algorithm is, strictly speaking, merely the mathematical definition of a set of cryptographic functions (encryption, decryption, and possibly signing). The definition of the algorithm may provide certain constraints, including allowable key lengths.

But choosing an algorithm is only one part of creating a secure cryptosystem. The others are:

1. Selecting an attack-resistant software or hardware implementation
2. Key management:

   1. Generation
   2. Distribution
   3. Decommission
   4. Retention
   5. Revocation / Destruction

So to have a secure AES based cryptosystem, you need to have a good implementation of it, and good key management.

To have a secure OTP cryptosystem, you need to have sufficiently random keys, ensure they're only used once, and have a secure distribution system for them.

In either case, poor key management doesn't mean you're not using the specified algorithm.

Comment: Definitions can be pretty squirrelly things, but Schneier is pretty clear on the need for "truly random" numbers, which is why one-time pads are famous for being "perfectly secure" if the pad is kept a secret.  Do you have a source for your definition, or a reason for allowing "not-very-random" numbers?

Comment: @Proteus, your answer is wrong.  To qualify as a one-time pad, the key material must be uniformly random: i.e., if you are encrypting a single n-bit message, the key must be chosen uniformly at random from the set of all n-bit values.  If you are generating your key via some not-very-random process, it no longer qualifies as a one-time pad (OTP).  See Shannon's original paper on the subject.

Comment: @D.W., you're conflating "what's a one-time-pad" with "what's a *secure* one-time-pad".  OTPs have been around a long time, and can be implemented insecurely with non-random key material, just as *any* cipher can be used with insecure keys.  If you're generating your OTP key material with non-random keys, it's insecure, but as long as you never use that key again it is technically an OTP.

Comment: @nealmcb - see my response to @D.W., but also note that it's important to distinguish between OTP and *secure* OTP. The randomness of the key never defines the algorithm itself.

Comment: Any proper algorithm definition has to define how to do good keys.  It seems quite silly to define things so we would need to distinguish a "secure" version of every protocol.  E.g. to say that AES is insecure, but "secure AES" requires good keys and is thus secure.  Without a citation of some sort, we can't take what you say as anything other than your personal opinion.  OTP is one of those things that people generally talk about only because of its famously secure nature.  To define it in a way that undermines that just invites confusion.

Comment: @Proteus, I'm with @nealmcb.  The specification of an encryption scheme includes three algorithms: encryption, decryption, and key generation.  In the case of the OTP, the key generation algorithm is defined to be a uniform random choice of a key of the same size as the message.  At this point I think if you want to tell @nealmcb he's using the term incorrectly, an authoritative reference/citation would be appropriate.

Comment: @D.W. and @nealmcb - ok, look. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad#True_randomness_requirements  That's a section of the reference you yourself use, neal.  It talks about generating pads that are deterministic, and how this makes for a less-secure OTP implementation.  It then goes on to talk about achieving Shannon security.  The NIST specification for AES (http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf) makes a distinction between the algorithm specification and "Implementation considerations" like proper key generation. Key generation IS NOT a part of an algorithm spec.

Comment: I'll trust a reference to Schneier or Shannon any day over a wikipedia page, especially since I don't see the wikipedia text referring to the "empirical security" as OTP.  And in the same section it does call OTP "perfect" according (again) to Shannon.  I can see a certain logic in your way of defining things, but it just seems to me that people treat OTP in a special way.

Comment: Just my tuppence worth - there are certain perfectly valid scenarios where using a truly random OTP would not be feasible. If you look at espionage you'll see where I'm coming from on this. Sometimes you need to use an OTP which must look innocuous - perhaps words/chars in a book or something else which an enemy may find. They would be suspicious of a table of random numbers, but may not notice a book. (I know - sounds a lot like security through obscurity - gah!)

Comment: @nealmcb so let me get this straight. You're ignoring the NIST resource and basic cryptosystem theory because Shannon wrote a paper on achieving perfect security with OTP? Look, there's a reason that NIST has an entire separate practice for key managment: http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/key_management.html  Key management is a separate -- and perhaps even more important -- problem from algorithm selection.  Algorithms are *not defined* by the randomness of their keys, that's an implementation consideration.  You need to cite your sources.

Comment: This is getting silly, especially since my answer wasn't especially dogmatic about this point.  I did go ahead and add "classic" to qualify my answer.  But to be more specific about the Schneier source, it is **Applied Cryptography**, Second Edition, p 15: "Clasically, a one-time pad is nothing more than a large nonrepeating set of truly random key letters".  And note that key management is hard mostly because of key distribution problems, not key generation, which is very algorithm-specific.  Don't try RSA with just any old key....

Comment: @rory Thanks for injecting a ray of practical perspective into the discussion.   I'm no expert on espionage, but I would suggest at least that such spies not use text as a key for text since they share such a similar distribution and the ciphertext would be clearly identifiable and vulnerable.

Comment: @nealmcb - +1 totally agree, was just going for the simplest item off the top of my head.

Comment: http://users.telenet.be/d.rijmenants/en/onetimepad.htm is an interesting overview of the history of operational use of OTP.